# Excel: Sum a range of cells if a related key is in a range of values using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I'm trying to return the sum of a range of cells if an associated value is in a range of values used as filtering conditions. For example, using the following data table:

```
  Keys      Values
   A        500
   B        300
   C        600
   D         20
   A        150
   C        600
```

and the following list of keys to be summed:

```
Sum Keys:
   A
   D
```

I'm looking for a formulaic way to return 500+20+150 = 670.

I know you can use multiple SUMIFs, but the number of keys will change based on what the user wants to filter on, and writing enough SUMIFs to cover the max realistic cases (like 10ish) seems excessive, and I feel like there must be an easier way.

In my head, the formula would look something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Values, Keys, OR(Sum Keys), ...(optional other conditions))
```

I realize that this is an easy VBA problem, but I'm trying to avoid that because the spreadsheet will be audited by people with varying (or no) VBA knowledge. Also, adding an indicator column to the data to show if the key is in the `Sum Keys` range isn't realistic because there will be multiple tabs summarizing the data, each with their own filters on `Key`

Any help is appreciated, though I realize this may be impossible without VBA. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks barry houdini for the answer! See the comments of his post for the general solution for summing based on multiple ranges of acceptable criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a formula like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Values,Key,Sum_Keys))`

If Sum_Keys has 4 values then the SUMIFS formula returns a 4 value "array" (one for each Key in Sum_Keys) so you then need another function to sum that array. I use SUMPRODUCT because it avoids the need for "array entry".

You can add more conditions in the usual way, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Values,Key,Sum_Keys,Dates,Specifc_date))`

Comment: Curious question - can you do this for multiple fields? For example, `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Values, Key, Sum_Keys, Dates, Sum_Dates))`? This works if Sum_Dates is only one value, but if it's a range it only returns the first match.

Comment: That's trickier...one of Sum_Keys and Sum_Dates must be a column of values and one must be a row of values, then it works - if they are both columns (or both rows) you can TRANSPOSE one in the formula - =SUM(SUMIFS(Values, Key, Sum_Keys, Dates, TRANSPOSE(Sum_Dates0)) - that needs CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: ...also you have reached the limit with 2 multiple criteria - to do unlimited (almost) switch to `SUMPRODUCT` syntax like `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Key,Sum_Keys,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Dates, Sum_Dates,0)),Values)`....although that will be slower than SUMIFS, especially with whole columns

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum items in accordance to filter conditions, consider using the

**=SUBTOTAL()**

worksheet function.  It is the tool to handle this task.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: I can't filter the data directly because multiple tabs will be using the data in a similar fashion with their own filtering keys. I want to use a formula to sum the data for A and D, but can't physically filter the data on those keys - the formula must do that.